# Socket.io on socket disconnect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have this scenario with socket.io:

A socket connects and joins a room and he is the master. Other sockets join his room. When master disconnects I want to kick all other sockets from this room.

I thought of this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
    // if socket's id == room  he is the master and kick other sockets from this 
    // room and join them to a room of their own identified by their ids.       
});
```

I want to do this without too much logic and for loops to stall the application. Is it possible to something like `io.sockets.leave(socket.room)`?

Answer (score 5):

alessioalex's answer returns an error because it tries to call "leave" on an array of sockets. This is a working solution:

```
io.sockets.clients(socket.room).forEach(function(listener) {
    listener.leave(socket.room);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not 100% sure, but after reading [Socket.IO's documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io) on github I think this should work:

```
io.sockets.in(socket.room).leave(socket.room);
```