# Disconnect All Users of Room when "Host" Disconnects in Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, redis, express, socket.io

Currently I have the originator of a room marked as the "Host".
I need to set it so that if the "Host" clicks a "Close Room" link, it will disconnect all over users from that room id.

How can I grab all users from `socket.manager.roomClients` or something of the sorts, loop through them all and run some type of `socket.leave( room_id )` if the "Host's" room_id matches the key in the socket manager?

Thanks for any insight or help. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517242/socket-io-on-socket-disconnect Maybe that answer will work for you.

Comment: Ya, I found that question before posting mine. The proposed answer does not work. Simply crashes node.js with an error. `TypeError: Object #<SocketNamespace> has no method 'leave'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a mechanism for this in socket.io, but it's not terribly difficult to implement it yourself. You just iterate over each socket in the room and call the disconnect method. This would ideally be a io.sockets level method, but you've got to know the namespace that the socket is using, so I added a prototype at the socket level to boot everyone out of a room. Take a look at the following:

```
var sio = require('socket.io');
var io = sio.listen(app);

sio.Socket.prototype.disconnectRoom = function (name) {
    var nsp = this.namespace.name
    , name = (nsp + '/') + name;

    var users = this.manager.rooms[name];

    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        io.sockets.socket(users[i]).disconnect();
    }

    return this;
};
```

You can use it as shown below.

```
socket.on('hostdisconnect', function() {
    socket.disconnectRoom('roomName');
});
```

A word of warning, if you're going to use something like this, it's important to be aware it uses internal data structures which may or may not be around in the next version of socket.io. It's possible for an update from socket.io to break this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The latest update in socket.io is the leave() method as a companion to join().

Eg;

```
    socket.join('room1');
    socket.leave('room1');
```

May be this help you in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I managed to achieve this in `socket.io "version": "2.1.1"` :

```
function disconnectRoom(room: string, namespace = '/') {
   io.of(namespace).in(room).clients((err, clients) => {
      clients.forEach(clientId => this.io.sockets.connected[clientId].disconnect());
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much fighting with trying to do it through socket.io I figured out a way to get the room to be killed through Node.JS/Express

```
app.get('/disconnect', function(req, res){
  console.log("Disconnecting Room " + req.session.room_id);
  req.session.destroy(function(err){
    if (err){
      console.log('Error destroying room... ' + err);
    } else{
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This will just destroy session, without affecting soket.io room anyway. 
Atleast as i understand it.